# Compound two views in one

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I've a custom view that extend from view now I want to compound two of them in one and make a new custom view. Now I want to know whether I should redraw my child views in new  custom view or there is a way to add them in new custom view.

```
public class Selector extends View {

    // properties and methods

    private void init(Context context) {

    }

    public Selector(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init(context);
    }

    public Selector(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        init(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        // set measures
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // drawing
    }
}
```

Now I want to compound two of Selectors in a view. how can I do it? Thanks

Comment: read about ViewGroup class

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this

```
public class myView extends LinearLayout {
  public myView(Context context) {
       super(context);

       addView(new Selector(context));
       addView(new Selector(context))
   }


}
```

Comment: Thanks, But I would have overlapped mode and also I've tested FrameLayout that there is a problem in this situation that is that I'm not able to click on the following view!